# Why is glGenVertexArrays defined for a C program but not a C++ program on Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, opengl, opengl-es-2.0

Consider the following file:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>

int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", 0, 0, 200, 200, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
}
```

If the above is test.c, then the following line (compiling as C code) works perfectly:

```
gcc test.c -I/usr/include/SDL2 -lGLESv2 -lSDL2
```

This next one (compiling as C++ code), however, does not:

```
gcc -x c++ test.c -I/usr/include/SDL2 -lGLESv2 -lSDL2
```

The error that I get is:

```
test.c: In function ‘int main()’:
test.c:9:27: error: ‘glGenVertexArrays’ was not declared in this scope
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
```

I am compiling this on x86 Linux with gcc 4.8.2, using SDL 2.0 and OpenGL ES 2.0.

What is going on?  Many of the other OpenGL ES 2.0 calls that I make (glDrawArrays, glGenBuffers, etc.) work perfectly well with both C and C++.  Additionally, isn't C++ supposed to be able to call C libraries, especially system ones that (should) be designed to prevent function name mangling?

What is wrong, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Works perfectly? You need to at least compile with -Wall to claim that.

Comment: @n.m.: There are both false positives and false negatives with `-Wall`.

Comment: There are more false positives with -Wall than without, but less false negatives. Why trade one for the other? You can analyze and suppress a false positive.

Comment: @n.m., you are right that `-Wall` would have made that function call suspect, and I should have used it (in my defense, I am so used to compiling programs with a Makefile with -Wall that I forgot to specify it this time).

Comment: It is not, the only difference is that in C it is ***implicitly declared*** (C++ does not do this); it will pass the compile stage, but unless you link to an appropriate library it will fail to link in C. `glGenVertexArrays (...)` is not a part of OpenGL 2.0 *or* OpenGL ES 2.0, it was added to 3.0 in both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glGenVertexArrays.xhtml

The previous answer is also correct but doesn't really gives a solution. Nor mine actually. It's just that `glGenVertexArrays` is not supported by OpenGLES 2.

Solution : Use OpenGL ES 3.

Comment: as simple as that. Who would've thought of checking the doc!

Comment: @didierc and agrum, I didn't check the doc *because it worked under C which was the way it was supposed to work*!  My logic was that, because it worked under C, then (1) it must be in the spec and (2) it must work under C++ as well.  Nonetheless, thanks for the answer.

Comment: That is were I'm confused then. When you say it works, do you mean it compiles or it actually executes and do the job ?

Comment: @agrum, if the driver support GLES3, it could very well work.

Comment: Oh yes it'll work, but so far InkBlend has been using OpenGLES 2, so I am doubtful about the meaning of `it works`. Cause it shouldn't.

Comment: OK, HUGE apologies to everyone here; glGenVertexArrays() and glBindVertexArray() do NOTHING under OpenGL ES 2.0, even when they compile into C code.  I didn't even test it, I just automatically assumed that if it compiled, it would work.  That was a big mistake on my part, and I'm sorry about wasting your time by ignoring the things that you were trying to tell me (especially you, agrum).  Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: No worries, we all went through the same. OpenGL is especially nerve consuming concerning the compilation that goes through but the execution that doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Looking a the [`gl2.h` header](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/api/GLES2/gl2.h), it seems that the aformentioned function is not defined there. C++ has stricter rules with regard to function declaration and definition. In C, you may perfectly use a function which asn't been declared before hand, and the compiler will assume a certain prototype. In C++, any function must be at least declared before any use.

The section *5.2.2 - Function Call* of the C++ specification, sub paragraph 2 indicates that:

> Note: If a function or member function name is used, and name lookup (3.4) does not find a declaration of
>   that name, the program is ill-formed. No function is implicitly declared by such a call. — end note

That is where the difference lies with C. This may however indicate a deeper problem: either you are using the wrong header, and linking with an OpenGL implementation which support that function, or somehow, the header should contain that declaration and does not. My first guess would be that you should probably double check which OpenGL implementation you are effectively linking against, and whether the header you are using is the correct one.

However, it is also possible that this OpenGL standard keeps an definition of that function as an extension, or that the function is visible by the linker because the driver supports a higher standard or extension. Relying on that feature is of course not recommended without first checking that the corresponding extension is actually supported by the driver.