# Having Access Violation error in VS2012 using openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, access-violation

below is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glew.h>
#include <freeglut.h>

enum VAO_IDs{triangles, numVAOs};

const GLuint vPosition=0;

GLuint VAOs[numVAOs];

const GLuint window_width=700;
const GLuint window_height=300;

void init(){
    glClearColor(7,7,9,0);
    /*generate vertex array object*/
    glGenVertexArrays(numVAOs, VAOs); // <- breakpoint
    /*bind vertex array object*/
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[triangles]);
        //rest of code removed
}

void display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   
    glFlush();  //or glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitContextVersion(2,8);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_DEBUG);
    glutInitWindowSize(window_width, window_height);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello world to openGL");

    /*init the glew libarary*/
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum error=glewInit();
    if(GLEW_OK != error)
        std::cout<<"Glew libraray not initialized"  <<std::endl;                                                                  

    std::cout<<glGetString(GL_VERSION)<<std::endl;

    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

i am currently running on openGL 2.1 and the important thing is that the code is working fine on linux....
all the required libraries are included and mentioned in the dependency settings...
i even tried the same program in code::blocks but the same error at the same point. As this code is running in linux so that means it's not the hardware problem. The problem is in windows OS but don't know where. I am stuck.. help!!

on windows i tried this code in VS2013 and code::blocks (but fail) and is working on linux
using code::blocks.

following are the screenshots of errors First-Chance exception and Unhandled Exception:

[image]

[image]

i was somehow able to ignore First-Chance exception but don't know how to manage Unhandled exception.

Comment: what is the last relevant function in the call stack of the debugger ?

Comment: Was it working with OpenGL 2.1 on Linux ? Cause `glGenVertexArrays` is an OpenGL 3.3 function if I'm not wrong. Add -Wall in the compilation attribute to show all warnings. If this is a C an not a C++ program the fact that you call an undefined function may be hidden.

Comment: `glutInitContextVersion(2,8)`? There's no such thing as OpenGL 2.8.

Comment: Vetex Array objects are implemented in v2.0 and i am using dual boot both windows and linux that means same gl.... And thats v2.1

Comment: Good to know. There was a post previously with the same function use in OpenGL ES 2 while it was only supported in OpenGL ES 3, I thought it was the same for OpenGL. I can't find the info.

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGenVertexArrays Gaurav Sharma, Here it says it's in the Core since 3.0. Are you talking about the ARB ? EDIT : Oooh, it's included in glew, so you got it from the extension, not the Core.

Comment: Reto Koradi my fault.... Initially it was 4,3 but i modified it dont know why.... And it wasn't even working for that

Comment: Agrum.... Then how its working on linux????

Comment: different OpenGL or Glew package installed ? As said above, could you add -Wall or c++ parameter. We will be fixed if you use a function undefined.

Comment: You mean headers??? And libraries....... No i am just using the ones packed and build

Comment: OpenGL is not only about headers, but a first step to try to understand the problem would be to know if `glGenVertexArrays` is defined.

Comment: Well, if you knew nothing about freeGlut, the error says that an attempt is made to call a function at address 0.  That should give you a hint that internally, a function that should exist at runtime doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes... It is defined and i check that using #if defined glGenVertexArrays

Comment: @GauravSharma - Please look at the error that is generated at runtime. It definitely means that an internal function that needs to be called is being called, but it is vapor.

Comment: Take a look at this subject. It is closely related to your problem. Check the non validated answer, it'll help you solve this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020788/why-is-glgenvertexarrays-defined-for-a-c-program-but-not-a-c-program-on-linux

Comment: But the same code is working fine on linux.... Why????

Comment: Well you tell us. Are you sure that OpenGL, Glew and Glut are the SAME versions used in both projects ?

Comment: Yes they are same.....

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie but the same code is working fine on linux

Comment: Are you compiling your project as a C or C++ program ? (Yes it matters) If C, did you add the -Wall compilation parameter as asked before. If you are using an undefined function (and I don't want you to put an #ifdef) it will show up. If it doesn't I will gladly admit I made a wrong assumption and move on to an other idea. It will compile but you will get a warning about an undefined function, so don't hide the warnings.

Comment: @GauravSharma `But the same code is working fine on linux`. It isn't about the code. Sure, the same source code is used, but are the same libraries used?  Correct versions of the libraries?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie definitely.... I copied the same libraries from linux

Comment: @agrum it's C++ project

Comment: Excuse me what ? Like you copied the folders and stuff ? Ok, C++ project, so if you had an undefined function you should get an error at compilation. If it's not the case the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah the *.lib files that are required ,headers and dlls... Anything wrong in that?? I dont know

Comment: @agrum only the *.dll and *.a libraries vary for both environments

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that this is broken on Windows because the function pointer for `glGenVertexArrays` is `0`.  The extension wrangler will hide the retrieval of the function pointers from the user, but it basically boils down to a call to `wglGetProcAddress`, which is Windows-specific, because the Windows OpenGL implementation only provides GL 1.1.  On Linux, none of that happens (I think), or at least it happens differently, so that could be the difference between it running fine on Linux and crashing on Windows.

Comment: ktodisco has a point. Are your graphic drivers up to date on Windows ? Seems far fetched but who knows.

Comment: @agrum updating graphic drivers was the first thing i did after getting this error....

Comment: @agrum -- maybe the library is loading function pointers at runtime with the addresses of known functions, and for some reason a function that should exist doesn't exist. I would be surprised that the system doesn't report this at runtime, but that is one scenario where this can occur.  Again, I'm looking purely at the error generated from the exception, nothing else, and then working from there.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes and for the same reason i check my glew library and its support.... And all is working fine

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- I don't have enough background there. I try to think of a scenario where the compiler is fine about a function that is not here but nothing that a clean/rebuild wouldn't solve. I guess the OP is beyond that.

Comment: All is working fine now ?

Comment: Nope.... I mean all libraries and functions are included..

Comment: I just took a look at the freeglut project. Do you have to compile the library yourself ? I can find the headers but not the *.lib or *.dll. If you do have to compile the library, you said you copied the folder from Linux to Windows. Are you using libraries you compiled from Linux on Windows or did you recompile the library on Windows ?

Comment: If you download the zip freeglut project you will get both dll and libs inside....along with headers

Comment: If you took the MSVC package it should be fine. Anyway the function missing should be in glew not glut. You use the non static one for glew ? You do have the *.dll in the executable folder ?

Comment: @agrum yes non static...... The dlls are in system32 folder of windows

Comment: Your clear color makes me laugh. All of those numbers will be clamped to **1.0**.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman hahha yeah and make screen white.... But thats not the problem

Comment: I have a feeling I spent to much time on this question and I try to find a far fetched answer. I can't manage to find the source of the problem. I'll leave this to someone else, sorry.

Comment: @agrum well u even tried and thats appreciated...... Thanks for help

Comment: @GauravSharma - I just built the same application using `glut 1.9`, `freeglut 2.8.1` using Visual Studio 2013.  The only thing I changed was the call to `glutInitContextVersion` where I used `(3,3)` as the parameters.  Linked to `freeglut.lib` and `glew32.lib`.  I had no issues running the application (the Window shows up with no issues).  Make sure that you check that the freeglut.dll and glew32.dll are the correct ones that are loaded when running your application.  If you have previously installed these DLL's, maybe your app is picking up the old versions.

Comment: @GauravSharma - Also, I have very little knowledge of glut or even OpenGL.  I just downloaded the packages, built the app, and ran *your* example with the only change being the `glutInitContextVersion` function call.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i think i need to get updated dlls or i will try with 3,3 context.....but i dont think that context is affecting ?? I dont know... Okay thanks for that.... I am going to try this